# Web Service dependencies on another Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jboss

I have a web service `WebService1` that is deployed on JBoss (4.2.3.GA).
`WebService1`'s endpoint is `Endpoint1`.

I wrote a `WebService2` which dependends on `WebService1`. When Maven creates the .EAR file, it places the .JAR with `WebService1` in `WebService2`'s .EAR.

So, when I deploy `WebService2` in JBoss I get the exception:

```
Endpoint1 has already registered.
```

If I remove class with `Endpoint1` from the .JAR in the .EAR, then it's all normally deployed. But I can't remove this class after every project building.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dependency that you don't want packaged with your maven build, use the "provided" dependency scope like this:

```
<dependency>
  ..
  <scope>provided</scope>
  ..
</dependency>
```

This will allow Maven to compile the project, but won't include said dependency with the final package.  More information [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No. I need this package in runtime. I want exclude 1 class from dependency

Comment: ah, I see.  Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547805/how-to-exclude-all-transitive-dependencies-of-a-maven-dependency) what you're looking for?  Maven also provides a way to exclude certain classes from dependency libraries...

Comment: This exclude all package, not 1 class