# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-batch

Below is the pom.xml of my spring batch project and I get the below exception if I deploy in    jboss 5 ,   but the same war works fine if I deploy in local windows machine. I suspect there is a conflict  in jar with respect to `org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6`.

Even I tried excluding the spring core jar in spring batch dependency,  but I couldn't resolve this can anyone help thanks in advance.Is there a way to exclude  `spring-context:jar:2.5.6`

```
Error Trace 
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:369)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3910)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4389)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:313)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:145)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:122)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
 +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:2.5.6:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.0.RC2:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.0.RC2:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:org.springframework.web.servlet:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:org.springframework.beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:org.springframework.asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:org.springframework.context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:org.springframework.aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:org.springframework.context.support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:org.springframework.core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:org.springframework.expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:org.springframework.web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |     \- org.aopalliance:com.springsource.org.aopalliance:jar:1.0.0:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-struts:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- struts:struts:jar:1.2.9:compile
 |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
 |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
 |  |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.1.4:compile
 |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.7:compile
 |  |  \- xalan:xalan:jar:2.5.1:compile
 |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc-portlet:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
 +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.10:compile
 +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
 |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
 |  +- com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1:compile
 |  \- com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1:compile
 +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile
 +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.10:compile
 +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
 +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.15:compile
 +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
 +- aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.5.2:compile
 +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
 +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3:compile
 |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
 +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3:compile
 |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
 +- junit:junit:jar:4.0:compile
 +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
 +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
 +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
 +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
 +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
 +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
 +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
 +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
 +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.4.Final:compile
 +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.1.4.Final:compile
 +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:4.1.4.Final:compile
 +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
 +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
 +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
 +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
 +- com.oracle:ojdbc5:jar:11.2.0.2.0:compile
 +- org.skywaysoftware:skyway-spring-utils:jar:7.1.3:compile
 |  +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
 |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
 |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle-minimal:jar:2.1.9:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
 |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
 |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.9:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:2.0.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.9:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.3:compile
 |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.21:compile
 |  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.21:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:jar:1.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
 |  |  +- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
 |  |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
 |  |  +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1:compile
 |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.9:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec:jar:1.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec:jar:1.1.2:compile
 |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:2.2.3:compile
 |  |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.4.0:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.4.3:compile
 |  |  +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:compile
 |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.43:runtime
 |  +- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.8:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:2.0.4:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-support:jar:2.0.8:runtime
 |  \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.4.0.M1:compile
 |     \- opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11:compile
 +- com.ibm.mq.commonservices:com.ibm.mq.commonservices:jar:7.0.1.3:compile
 +- com.ibm.mq:dhbcore:jar:7.0.1.9:compile
 +- javax.resource:connector:jar:1.0:compile
 +- com.ibm.mq.headers:com.ibm.mq.headers:jar:7.0.1.3:compile
 +- com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq:jar:7.0.1.9:compile
 +- com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.jmqi:jar:7.0.1.9:compile
 +- com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mqjms:jar:7.0.1.9:compile
 +- com.sun.messaging.mq:fscontext:jar:4.4.2:compile
 +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
 +- simple-jndi:simple-jndi:jar:0.11.4.1:compile
 +- javax.transaction:jta:pom:1.0.1B:compile
 +- com.sun.jndi:providerutil:pom:1.2:compile
 +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-resources:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
 +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.6:compile
 +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jmx:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.6:compile
 +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile
 |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile
 |  +- org.scannotation:scannotation:jar:1.0.3:compile
 |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
 |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
 |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
 |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
 |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.0.3:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:compile
 |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
 \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:2.2.1.GA:compile
    +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.6.3:compile
    +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.6.3:compile
    +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.6.3:compile
    \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.6.3:compile
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycomp.pil</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>PIL: MyProject</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.framework.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <spring.integration.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
        <spring.batch.core>2.1.8.RELEASE</spring.batch.core>
        <spring.batch.admin>1.2.1.RELEASE</spring.batch.admin>
        <hibernate.core.version>4.1.4.Final</hibernate.core.version>
        <jboss.resteasy.version>2.2.1.GA</jboss.resteasy.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-js-resources</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
            <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate Dependancies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- OJDBC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc5</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skywaysoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>skyway-spring-utils</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- MQ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq.commonservices</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.commonservices</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.ibm.mq.connector</groupId> <artifactId>connector</artifactId> 
            <version>7.0.1.3</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId> 
            <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId> <version>7.0.1.3</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
            <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq.headers</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.headers</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.messaging.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>fscontext</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>simple-jndi</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jta</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1b</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jndi</groupId>
            <artifactId>providerutil</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Batch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.core}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>                                                     
        spring-batch-infrastructure                                    
      </artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.core}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.core}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-integration</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-resources</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-admin-manager</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.admin}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <!-- <excludes> <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude> </excludes> -->
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 13):

You are mixing Spring 3.1.1 with Spring 2.5.6. Add explicit dependencies or dependency management entries for those Spring dependencies that are still on 2.5.6 to upgrade them to 3.1.1 or downgrade your project.

Comment: Hi Rec Thanks for the response ,Which one are you refering to as 2.5.6 .Can you point out that .

Comment: Well, look at what you posted yourself: org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6, etc. There is even a 3.1.0.RC2 in there. All Spring dependencies should have the same version. Just add explicit dependencies on the 3.1.1 version for all of these artifacts to your pom instead of relying on transitive inclusion.

Comment: Yes Rec i understand i am missing out something here , spring-context:jar:2.5.6 or spring-beans:jar:2.5.6 is in the dependency tree , but i did not add them explicitly,I am finding trouble in removing them as i need to use 3..1.1 .could you please suggest

Comment: Maven uses the principle of the "closest version". "Close" means, how many dependency steps away from your project. So if you do not explicitly include these dependencies in the correct version yet, then start doing it. Nothing is "closer" than the dependency defined in the pom itself. Excluding them can lead to problems as other dependency may need them. Otherwise, refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547805/how-to-exclude-all-transitive-dependencies-of-a-maven-dependency) for an example of how to exclude a dependency. I wouldn't recommend it in your situation though.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of spring jars have you packaged as part of the war? Does it have 2.5.6? Does your war referring it @ run time from anywhere else?

I can see the below ways to identify the root cause,
1. Start the server in remote debug mode. 
2. If not, may be try out jboss scoped class loading,

Create jboss-web.xml under WEB-INF,

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
      <loader-repository>
         com.example:archive=<<webarchive name>>
         <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
      </loader-repository>
   </class-loading>
<jboss-web>
```

Replace it with <> your web archive file name.

See, if this helps...