# Issue while deploying application in jboss on unix enviroment

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

On starting my jboss application server, I am getting following error:

```
0:27:03,456 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-5) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
10:27:03,479 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-5) Context initialization failed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.setId(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:264) [org.springframework.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197) [org.springframework.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:3.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final-redhat-1.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:89) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
```

the application works fine on my local windows machine, and I have exactly the same server in the **UNIX** machine, where it does not work.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: It seems that you are using different version of Spring on UNIX. Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601279/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-web-context-configurablewebappl

Comment: (1) Are the Spring JARs packaged inside your application or do they exist in an external library? (2) Can you confirm that there are not 2 versions of the JARs inside your application *at the same time*? (e.g. `spring-3.0.3.jar`, `spring-2.5.3.jar`)

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos: This was indeed the issue. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates that one of your Spring Jars is the wrong version.  `ConfigurableWebApplicationContext` does not have the `setId` method in [version 2.0](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.html).  But this method does appear in the version [3.x version of Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.html).

Comment: But, I have the same application and server on local windows machine which works absolutely fine.

Comment: It was due to another spring jar which was there in my war. Fixed it. Although not able to understand why I only got issue on UNIX machine and not my local windows machine. I guess something to do with classloading.