# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRResourcesUtil.findClassLoaderResource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to export user list in database to pdf. When I clicked my"Print table" button this exception returns. Button is actioning generateReport() method.

Some Details:

- iReport 5.5.0
- net.sf.jasperreports 5.5.0 (pom.xml)
- jasperreports 3.5.3 (pom.xml)
- Glassfish 4.0
- JDK 1.8
- Netbeans 8.1

Glassfish log file is here :

```
[2016-08-20T02:31:33.161+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1471649493161] [levelValue: 800] [[
  generateReport()]]
[2016-08-20T02:31:33.161+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1471649493161] [levelValue: 800] [[
  TTTT -:C:\Users\Burak\Documents\NetBeansProjects\question3\target\question3-1.0-SNAPSHOT\jasper\JRUser1.jrxml]]
[2016-08-20T02:31:33.163+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=Thread-4] [timeMillis: 1471649493163] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Sat Aug 20 02:31:33 EEST 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.]]
[2016-08-20T02:31:33.165+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1471649493165] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Context Path is  : =C:\Users\Burak\Documents\NetBeansProjects\question3\target\question3-1.0-SNAPSHOT\jasper\JRUser1.jrxml]]
[2016-08-20T02:31:33.645+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1471649493645] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Compiling Report Designs]]
[2016-08-20T02:31:34.082+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1471649494082] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Creating JasperPrint Object]]
[2016-08-20T02:31:34.107+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1471649494107] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[users]: Servlet.service() for servlet users threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRResourcesUtil.findClassLoaderResource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/net/URL;
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getInputStream(DefaultRepositoryService.java:141)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.InputStreamPersistenceService.load(InputStreamPersistenceService.java:48)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getResource(DefaultRepositoryService.java:187)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.findInputStream(RepositoryUtil.java:304)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInputStreamFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:275)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:183)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:107)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:80)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:177)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:78)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:60)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:147)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:421)
    at obss.question3.springmvc.controller.ListUserController.generatePdfReport(ListUserController.java:95)
    at obss.question3.springmvc.controller.ListUserController.generateReport(ListUserController.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Error in web browser :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRResourcesUtil.findClassLoaderResource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/net/URL;
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRResourcesUtil.findClassLoaderResource(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/net/URL;
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

ListUserController is here:

```
@Controller
public class ListUserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    ServletContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list-users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listUsersPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Web Demo with Spring Security");

        model.addObject("person", new Users());
        model.addObject("listPersons", this.userService.getAllUsers());

        System.out.println("listusers()");
        model.setViewName("/secured/list-users");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/generateReport", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String generateReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException {
        System.out.println("generateReport()");
        HashMap<String, Object> hmParams = new HashMap<>();
        hmParams.put("Title", "Test");

        String contextPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/jasper/JRUser1.jrxml");

        System.out.println("TTTT -:" + contextPath);

        try {
            generatePdfReport(request); //Line 66
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ListUserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return "redirect:/list-users";
    }

    public void generatePdfReport(HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {

        String contextPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/jasper/JRUser1.jrxml");

        JasperConnection jc = new JasperConnection();
        Connection conn = jc.getConn();

        try {

            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(contextPath));

            System.out.println("Context Path is  : =" + contextPath);
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);

            System.out.println("Compiling Report Designs");
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

            System.out.println("Creating JasperPrint Object");
            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("ReportTitle", "PDF JasperReport");

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn); //Line 95

            File f = new File("/webapp/UserReport.pdf");
            f.createNewFile();

            // Exporting the report
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(f);

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output);

            System.out.println("Report Generation Complete");
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

JasperConnection is here:

```
public class JasperConnection {

    public Connection getConn() {
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/question3?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "password";

            // Load the Connector/J driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            // Establish connection to MySQL
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

JRUser1.jrxml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports 
http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
              name="JRUser1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" 
              leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     users.`username` AS users_username,
     users.`email` AS users_email,
     users.`birthday` AS users_birthday,
     users.`sex` AS users_sex
FROM
     `users` users]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="users_username" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="users_email" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="users_birthday" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="users_sex" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <group name="users_username">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{users_username}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="users_email">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{users_email}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="users_birthday">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{users_birthday}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="users_sex">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{users_sex}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[User Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Username]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="110" y="0" width="170" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="280" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Birthday]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="380" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Sex]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="4" width="100" height="15"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{users_username}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="120" y="4" width="170" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{users_email}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="280" y="4" width="100" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, $P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format( $F{users_birthday} )]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="380" y="4" width="100" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{users_sex}.equals( new Integer(0) ) ? "Male" : "Female"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**I deleted uuid parts in .jrxml. uuid attributes are causing another exceptions.**

**users_sex field type is smallint mysql. iReport automatically created .jrxml file with type java.lang.Integer.**

JRUser1.jrxml preview :

[image]

I searched but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

this problem happened when you have same **lib 2 versions**

or you **don't close the stream** generator file .pdf

investigations solutions for this

- run maven
- dependency:tree
- Analises your dependencies duplicante
- remove dependency more old
- see your method generatePdfReport many stream not closed, you need close all open stream

Comment: I closed output and input streams. It didn't affect. I runned "mvn dependency:analyze" command and it gaved some warnings. I runned another command "mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose" , it gaved omitted for duplicate and omitted for conflict infos. Should I remove all of them? I am newbie on maven.

Comment: that command only show duplicate lib, for remove one arterfact, see explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547805/exclude-all-transitive-dependencies-of-a-single-dependency or similar subject