# compilation fails inspite required entries in pom.xml (commons-lang3)

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

**Overview**

This may be a trivial question or may not be eligible to be here but any suggestion will be helpful.

When a dependency is added to the `pom.xml` bunch of errors show up while compiling a project into java jar without any code change what so ever

**Steps**

- Clone a git repo for the project and execute `mvn clean compile`

  ```
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] Total time: 4.743 s
  [INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-31T22:21:04+00:00
  [INFO] Final Memory: 25M/389M
  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```
- Add new required dependency to pom.xml of the same project [MVN Ref](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.storm/storm-hive/1.1.1)

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-hive</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Now again execute `mvn clean compile`

  ```
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project saavn-storm-lib: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
  [ERROR] /home/user/backend/storm/storm_lib/src/main/java/com/storm/bolts/Helper.java:[167,57] unreported exception org.json.JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

  .

  .

  .

  .
  ```

  Multiple occurrences of JSONException related error message, followed by

  ```
  [ERROR] /home/user/backend/storm/storm_lib/src/main/java/com/storm/bolts/Helper.java:[132,58] cannot find symbol
  [ERROR] symbol:   method unescapeJson(java.lang.String)
  [ERROR] location: class org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils
  ```

**More info**

- `pom.xml` contains

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Corresponding dependency is present locally as well

  ```
  ls -l ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/

  commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
  commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar.sha1
  commons-lang3-3.3.2.pom
  commons-lang3-3.3.2.pom.sha1
  _remote.repositories
  ```
- This method is deprecated in subsequent releases but it is very much present in this version and it was working so far.

**Question**

- Why these were not shown in the first place as they seems to be present already, given no code was modified ?
- `JSONException` related errors can be taken care of but why some dependency is suddenly missing and how to rectify that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two most likely scenarios:

1. There was a already a dependency on a different version of `storm-hive` before you added that dependency. If you go back to the working state (before you added the dependency) and call the Maven goal `dependency:list`, you might already see a `storm-hive` in the list.
2. There is a different dependency in the dependency:list that shares qualified class names with `storm-hive`. If you have different classes with same names on your classpath, Java just picks one of them and this might lead to strange errors.

Comment: With the pointers above I searched little more and stumbled across [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547805/exclude-all-transitive-dependencies-of-a-single-dependency). This helped in unblocking. But the question remains as to how to efficiently identify dependencies causing problems? I used `dependency : analyse` `dependency : tree` while poking around.

Comment: Why do you need exclusions? What do you mean by "dependencies causing problems"?

Comment: I checked for anything conflicting with `storm-hive` but did not find anything. So is it likely that some other packages that are pulled as a result of this particular entry might be creating problems I am facing ? That is what I referred to as _dependencies causing problems_ but what  I meant was packages.

Comment: Instead excluding as suggested in previous comment, just putting `storm-hive` dependency as the last one in the order while declaring in the `pom.xml` solved the problem.

Comment: Probably dependencyManagement would be a better Solution