# How to remove stax-api from maven build

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven EAR project with five moduls (EAR,JPA,WSVC,WSVCRouter,Properties).
When i trigger the build, I want to prevent stax-api from building as part of EAR.
I have googled and found out the exceptions tag, I have used it in all the places where I have dependency tag but still this jar is not excluded. Can anyone please help me on this. Thanks !!!

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>


      <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>  

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cnasurety.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.2</version>
           <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>   
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cnasurety.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.4</version>

        <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cnasurety.testutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>

        <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cna.tech.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-invocation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.0</version>

        <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cna.tech.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-invocation-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                 <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>


            <exclusion>
                        <groupId>stax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-tools-common</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>


            <exclusion>
                        <groupId>stax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>


            <exclusion>
                        <groupId>stax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>


            <exclusion>
                        <groupId>stax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>


            <exclusion>
                        <groupId>stax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>

        <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>

        <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>

        <!-- SLF4J logging API and implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>

        <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>

        <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>

        <exclusions>
                         <exclusion>
                                <groupId>stax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

enter code here
```

Comment: You seemed to add exclusions without thinking about it. Check first where the dependency `stax-api` is coming from...This can be done by using `mvn dependency:tree`...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://javadeveloperzone.com/maven/maven-show-dependency-tree/) to see if any other library don't use the stax-api?

In this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.stream/stax-api/usages) shows that 348 other libs use the stax-api.

Other thing you can try it`s use [bannedDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391251/7179003).

Best Regards

Comment: Hi Renan Souza,
Thanks very much for your help. This helped me in finding out the exact problem in where the dependency is present and now the Stax2 api is not part of the build. 

Apache - CXF common utils requires this jar. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi 
I have removed the stax api from the build  thanks to your suggestions
But im unable to remove another jar (neethi.jar from the build). I have found in the dependency tree from where it is being used, but still neethi,jar is not getting removed from the EAR file. please advise

Comment: Hi Jackson, for this dependency I found [those](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.neethi/neethi/usages) libs. Are your project private or can you share on GitHub?

Comment: Hi Renan Souza, 
Thanks again, I have added exclusion to all CXF dependencies and now i got it removed from the ear. Thanks again !!!

Comment: Jackson2489, can you help me and mark as resolved :D