# Maven exclude groupId wildcard usage

Tags: maven

Is it possible to exclude all dependencies starting with com.acme* in groupId?

Example:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>test</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.acme*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You can use wildcards yes. Have you tried your current example? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547805/exclude-all-transitive-dependencies-of-a-single-dependency or http://www.smartjava.org/content/maven-and-wildcard-exclusions/

Comment: Sure i tried the example, it doesn't exclude depedencies starting with "com.acme".

Comment: Ok, so from the second link in my previous comment we can see the filter is implemented in maven with the following line: `"*".equals( pattern ) || pattern.equals( value );` This means you can use `*` as a wildcard, but not in combination with any other characters. So the answer to your question would currently be `no`. You need a full match on the `groupId`, and then you can ignore all `artifactId` values by using the wildcard. You would need to repeat this for each groupid. Posting this as a comment instead of an answer, because there might be other options i don't know of.